# Can I get hired without interview task as midlevel developer?

Tags: interviewing

I am first time looking for a job as a non junior, and I'm surprised how big tasks interviewers give me to do as interview tasks. The tasks also almost always include something new to learn, so when working full time I simply don't have time to do this big tasks. I can work on weekends, but that is often not enough to meet the deadline, and it is very challenging to work 16 hours in weekdays and I really don't want to compromise my current job by being exhausted.

I have some projects in GitHub, but even when they check them, it's not enough. Once I was even told, "we use this technology you are familiar with, but can you make the task with this other technology we don't use and you are not familiar with, because we want to see what kind of decisions you make". So it feels like companies specifically want me to learn something new for interview, instead of showing what I can already do.

Can I just make more projects to GitHub in my free time and hope one day it will be enough so that someone will hire me based on them?

Comment: "Can I just ... hope one day it will be enough so that someone will hire me" - Don't do *just* that. Do that, but also keep looking for opportunities that require the skills you already have. If you don't feel you want to do a 16-hour interview task, you can always withdraw from the interrviews that expect that.

Comment: [This question I linked](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32808/is-there-a-professional-way-to-refuse-a-time-consuming-programming-task-given-as)  is not an exact duplicate, but your question, as is, doesn't seem on topic - there could certainly exist a company out there that doesn't require a coding task, we can't tell you whether you'd be able to find one, that has a job you want, though. There is also a lot of variability in the complexity and duration of coding tasks - requiring anywhere from less than an hour to days, from "hello world" to rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

This experience is basically telling you that you don't yet have the skills to reach to the jobs that you're applying for.  If you need to reach unreasonably high to meet the interview requirements, it's unlikely that you're a good fit for the jobs being offered.

You need to build up these skills, gain some experience and keep throwing projects into GitHub.

You're not quite ready yet.